# Print DOC files - Aspose.Words

Tags: java, printing, doc, aspose.words

Recently i was working on this library and made some small programs just to check the functionality. Now at this point i just know that we can Print Doc files by using Aspose.Words Java Library.

What i need to ask is How can I select Printer programatically using Aspose.Words. We already have option to show Print Dialog and then user can select Printer. But i need to do it with out Showing any Dialog. And one more request if you can help regarding setting Tray Number programatically, I'd be obliged. Thanks a lot for looking into my issue.

Regards,
Maher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Aspose.Words API, you can select the printer by specifying the printer name.

```
Document doc = new Document(srcDoc);
doc.print("Microsoft XPS Document Writer");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Is there any possibility i can set Tray Number ? Using Aspose.Words or Core Java ? I really need help regarding this issue. Thanks for kind response.

Comment: One of the support member replied in detail at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/631560.aspx. Please have a look